# Breadcrumbs are not shown on zend2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to get the breadcrumbs on a Zend Framework 2 project but unfortunately they didn't apper on the page. 
I've configured the navigation on the module.config.php as follows:

```
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Home',
            'route' => 'home',
            'pages' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Support',
                    'route' => 'home',
                    'action' => 'support',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Blog',
            'route' => 'post',
            'pages' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Admin',
                    'route' => 'post',
                    'action' => 'admin',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

And on the layout.phtml I've tried to show the breadcrumbs with each of the following methods, but without any success:

```
echo $this->navigation('navigation')->breadcrumbs()->setMinDepth(0)->setPartial('partial/breadcrumb.phtml'); (please note that I've also created the necessary breadcrumb.phtml)

echo $this->navigation('navigation')->breadcrumbs()->setMinDepth(0);

echo $this->navigation('navigation')->breadcrumbs()->render();
```

Can you help me please with a hint please? Please note that the routes from the navigation are also valid.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setPartial('partial/breadcrumb.phtml'); 

echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setPartial('MODULENAME/partial/breadcrumb.phtml');
```

Comment: I've tried with $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setPartial('Application/partial/breadcrumb.phtml') but it doesn't work, I receive the following error: Fatal error: Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException: Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "Application/partial/breadcrumb.phtml"; resolver could not resolve to a file

Also, the same path type ('partial/breadcrumb.phtml') works for menu partial.

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code in my application

```
<?php echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs('navigation')->setMinDepth(0)->setMaxDepth(3)->setLinkLast(false)->render();?>
```

This should work